# Django: Two fields form a key?

Tags: python, database, django

I have a model in Django 1.2.4. It has two fields that I would like to act together as a key. Is this possible?

This [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#common-model-field-options) only talks about a single field being a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may know this already, but one option would be to force the pair is unique and let Django add its own Primary Key.  So suppose you want two fields to be a primary key, well, make them [unique together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) and then make each of those fields a [db index](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly from [this](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) link, this ticket is not done yet, you can find more info in the link about how to do it "not directly" .